# I want to get a last inserted id

Tags: mysql, controller, cakephp-3.0

There are 2 tables quotedetails and quotationmaster and one common field QuoteNo. SNO is the primary key of quotation master. I want to get the maximum of sno and using it i want to insert same QuoteNo into 2 different tables. 
Heres my code.

```
$response = '';
$customer=TableRegistry::get('quotationmaster');
$query=$customer->query();
$this->set(array('data'=>$query));
$response = $customer->find();
foreach($response as $row)
{
    //echo $row['QuoteNo'];
    $x++;
}
$qno = $x + 1;
$nqno = 'Q1-'.$qno;
 $query->insert(['QuoteNo'])->
 values(['QuoteNo'=>$nqno])->execute();
 if($query) 
{
    $this->Flash->success('Saved');
    $this->redirect(['controller'=>'Stockcheck','action'=>'index']);
}   

$quotedetails=TableRegistry::get('quotationmaster');
$detquery=$quotedetails->query();
$options = $detquery->select(['QuoteNo'],['SerialNO' => $query->func()->MAX('SNO')]);
$qresponse = $quotedetails->find('all', $options);


Any helps are appreciable...
```

Comment: No offense, but that looks really weird. Testing `$query` will always be truthy, the second argument of `Query::select()` expects a boolean value, not an array, and the second argument of `Table::find()` expects an array, not a query object. You should see a bunch of errors when running that code. Are you sure that you know what you are doing there? I would suggest to study the docs a little more, so that you get a better understanding of how things work, and then maybe use `Table::save()` instead of manually inserting records.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use:

```
echo $this->SNO->getInsertID();
echo $this->SNO->getLastInsertID();
```

You can use any of the above method to get the last inserted ID.

Comment: No..Call to a member function getInsertID() on boolean  this error is throwing.